# Web service not handling simultaneous requests

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I have a web service, on an intranet, that basically sends emails.

From within various web applications - when an email is to be sent to a few hundred people, the subject, list of recipients etc. is stored in a database and an asynchronous call is made to the web service to send the emails.

```
Service1 myMailService = new Service1();
myMailService.SendMailAsync(EmailID);
```

The web service retrieves the data from the database and trundles through the recipients sending the emails. Sending out a few hundred emails can take a few minutes. The process works okay - in that the emails (usually) get sent.

But, it seems if say 3 people all have the application open and send emails at roughly the same time, not all the requests are processed. It is as if the web service cannot handle simultaneous requests. I have always assumed a web service would be able to handle simultaneous requests and handle threading itself.

Should a web service, by default, be able to handle simultaneous requests?

This is a Windows Server Standard - Service Pack 2 running IIS 7

The web service is very simple.

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
[SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay = true)]
public void SendMail(int EmailID)
{
//connect to the database, get a DataSet containing MessageDetails, List of Attachments, List of Recipients
//loop through the various data tables in the DataSet to get the data to create the email
//there are lots of try/catch/finally statements to make sure the database connection is closed
//send the email
smtpClient.Host = "myServer";
smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: "not all the requests are processed" - but in what way? The service returns without error, or it crashes, etc? It certainly should be able to handle multiple requests but if for example you are using a static instance of some class that's shared across requests, you might be running into trouble.

Comment: The service does not return anything to the client. The web service doesn't crash. It just does not process some of the requests sent to it. If a web service gets a request it can't handle for some reason - I guess it would write a log somewhere. But where? Can't see anything in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Is this your own web service or provided by a 3rd party?

Comment: My own web service. I have added an outline of the code above.

Comment: > //there are lots of try/catch/finally statements - are you you're not inadvertently swallowing an exception?

Comment: I'd say 'definitely' not. Any exception raised is written to the database. I haven't had one for nearly a year and the web service has been called many thousands of times with no problems. It just appears that, sometimes, if 3 people are sending emails within a few seconds of each other, some of them are not being sent. (The whole batch, that is, not individual emails within a request.)

Comment: OK, so can we split the problem - set the SMTP to use a drop directory instead of a direct host. Test with multiple clients and verify if all of the expected mail files are created in the drop directory. Perhaps it's the SMTP Host itself that is the issue.